# cannot override dragfinished method

Tags: codenameone

I have a subclass of the Button class and I would like to override the `dragFinished` method of the Component class. However, when I try to do this:

```
@Override
protected void dragFinished(int x, int y){
    // other code here
}
```

I am getting an error: `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`.

Also, if this provides more information, when I try to call `super.dragFinished(x, y)` within the method, I get this error: `dragFinished(int,int) is not public in Component; cannot be accessed from outside package.`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your IDE auto-completed inheritance from the wrong class e.g. `java.awt.Button` instead of `com.codename1.ui.Button`?

Comment: no, I have imported the correct class. I am able to override released() and pressed() but not able to override dragFinished().

Comment: I just verified this works correctly in the code. I noticed your code sample has a redundant `}` so that might be connected to the error.

Comment: is dragFinished by any chance only supported in a newer version of codenameone?

Comment: Newer than what? That's a pretty old method so unless you have a really old version of the plugin and didn't update the libraries of the project it should be fine. You can see the full sources and follow when it was added on github: http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/